# Javascript/JSON Object Array Search Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, search

I am trying to search results (that I get back from a SOAP API call) which are what I believe to be a Javascript object array since it doesn't follow JSON standards.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
[ { '$': { uuid: '{461F892D-07D8-4FCA-AF86-D5A9CBB080B8}' },
    pattern: [ '*689XXXX' ],
    description: [ 'DHHS_62' ],
    routePartitionName: [ 'DHHS_62-PT' ] },
  { '$': { uuid: '{84651C57-5E4C-4981-B859-38C8ECC56E3B}' },
    pattern: [ '*745XXXX' ],
    description: [ 'DHHS_43' ],
    routePartitionName: [ 'DHHS_43-PT' ] },
  { '$': { uuid: '{BC3259C4-38DB-4AD6-8594-61B938E4542C}' },
    pattern: [ '*753XXXX' ],
    description: [ 'DEQ_50' ],
    routePartitionName: [ 'DEQ_50-PT' ] },
  { '$': { uuid: '{4CF32D54-BED2-4167-A5E8-E0206520218A}' },
    pattern: [ '*7XXXXXXX' ],
    description: [ 'DNR_21' ],
    routePartitionName: [ 'DNR_21-PT' ] } ]
```

I have tried to use NPM modules [array-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-query) and [json-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-query) and neither work. I believe I am either doing something wrong to query the data, or I have dirty data that needs to be cleaned up.

Can anyone verify:

1. Is the data a JS array or dirty?
2. A query that uses the logic. (If "routePartitionName" = "DHHS_62-PT" then return "pattern"?

I think I'm way off in the weeds on this, and can't seem to find my way back to the road. I appreciate any help or advice!

Comment: What standards doesn't it follow it's a JSON-Array. Can you add one, of your tries to access the Array, so someone can improve it.

Comment: It is some kind of dirty data, you can change the `pattern`,`description`,`routePartitionName` can be change as string. And if you can clean the data format, then you can get a clear idea for query.

Comment: Are you against just iterating the array with a loop looking for that value?

Comment: Thanks, all for the help! 

Nikolaus, my understanding is that it originally is XML which has been translated to a JS array. I'm getting the data second hand though.

Gamsh, so you are saying that an entry should look like this?
{ pattern: '9.19005554444', description: 'Sample Outbound Call Block', routePartitionName: 'Blocked' }

Matt, nope not against that at all. 

Here are my attempt using array-query:
https://runkit.com/ajdrew/runkit-npm-array-query 

And my attempt using json-query:
https://runkit.com/ajdrew/runkit-npm-json-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the provided javascript is valid. Here is the filter function that goes through the whole object and returns a set of found patterns for a given routeParameterName.

test data

```
const obj = [{
        '$': {
            uuid: '{461F892D-07D8-4FCA-AF86-D5A9CBB080B8}'
        },
        pattern: ['*689XXXX'],
        description: ['DHHS_62'],
        routePartitionName: ['DHHS_62-PT']
    },
    {
        '$': {
            uuid: '{84651C57-5E4C-4981-B859-38C8ECC56E3B}'
        },
        pattern: ['*745XXXX'],
        description: ['DHHS_43'],
        routePartitionName: ['DHHS_43-PT']
    },
    {
        '$': {
            uuid: '{BC3259C4-38DB-4AD6-8594-61B938E4542C}'
        },
        pattern: ['*753XXXX'],
        description: ['DEQ_50'],
        routePartitionName: ['DEQ_50-PT']
    },
    {
        '$': {
            uuid: '{4CF32D54-BED2-4167-A5E8-E0206520218A}'
        },
        pattern: ['*7XXXXXXX'],
        description: ['DNR_21'],
        routePartitionName: ['DNR_21-PT']
    },
    {
        '$': {
            uuid: '{4CF32D54-BED2-4167-A5E8-E0206520218A}'
        },
        pattern: ['*6XXXXXX'],
        description: ['DNR_21'],
        routePartitionName: ['DNR_21-PT']
    }
];
```

function

```
function filter(data, key) {
    var patterns = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var routePartitionNames = data[i].routePartitionName;
        var currentPatterns = data[i].pattern;

        if (!Array.isArray(routePartitionNames) ||
            routePartitionNames.length === 0 ||
            routePartitionNames.indexOf(key) < 0
        ) {
            continue;
        }

        // key found in current routePartitionName
        for (var j = 0; j < currentPatterns.length; j++) {
            var currentPattern = currentPatterns[j];
            if (patterns.indexOf(currentPattern) < 0) {
                patterns.push(currentPattern);
            }
        }
    }
    return patterns;
}
```

usage: `filter(data, 'DNR_21-PT')`
returns: `["*7XXXXXXX", "*6XXXXXX"]`

Comment: thanks for the help! I like your function that worked. I have another dataset that I ran it on that would return multiple results. The script that keymotoe provided returns those multiple results. This one only returned 1 result. Any way it can return multiple?

Comment: Much appreciated. However, I tried the code and it still only returned 1 result. I copied and pasted your updated code exactly too. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe i misunderstood your question. Can there be multiple objects with the same routePartitionName? You want to return `all patterns` for `all objects` where a specific routePartitionName is set?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. My bad. Indeed, yes, there are multiple objects with the same routePartitionName. Also, yes, return all patterns for all objects where a specific routePartitionName is set.

Comment: Thank you very much! I greatly appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the object based on `routePartitionName` and then pass that to a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the desired pattern. There is probably a better way this is just quick and dirty.

```js
const obj = [ { '$': { uuid: '{461F892D-07D8-4FCA-AF86-D5A9CBB080B8}' },
    pattern: [ '*689XXXX' ],
    description: [ 'DHHS_62' ],
    routePartitionName: [ 'DHHS_62-PT' ] },
  { '$': { uuid: '{84651C57-5E4C-4981-B859-38C8ECC56E3B}' },
    pattern: [ '*745XXXX' ],
    description: [ 'DHHS_43' ],
    routePartitionName: [ 'DHHS_43-PT' ] },
  { '$': { uuid: '{BC3259C4-38DB-4AD6-8594-61B938E4542C}' },
    pattern: [ '*753XXXX' ],
    description: [ 'DEQ_50' ],
    routePartitionName: [ 'DEQ_50-PT' ] },
  { '$': { uuid: '{4CF32D54-BED2-4167-A5E8-E0206520218A}' },
    pattern: [ '*7XXXXXXX' ],
    description: [ 'DNR_21' ],
    routePartitionName: [ 'DNR_21-PT' ] } ]

let obj2 = obj.filter(item => item.routePartitionName == 'DHHS_62-PT').map(id => id.pattern);

console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: @AndrewPetersen If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This lets other users know the answer to the question when searching going forward.